# How can I avoid storing duplicates in the database in this code?

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have a user registration process which stores user info to my database using MYDAC components.  Currently it allow duplicate users, which is not my intention. My code is below, but I don't know where the problem is.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
  if (edit1.Text <> '') and (edit2.Text <> '') and (edit3.Text <> '') and 
    (edit4.Text <> '') then
  begin
    MyQuery1.Close;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from uyeler '+
                         'where nick=:0 and mail=:0 and site=:0';

    MyQuery1.Params[0].AsString:=edit1.text;
    MyQuery1.Params[0].AsString:=edit2.text;
    MyQuery1.Params[0].AsString:=edit3.text;

    MyQuery1.open;

    if MyQuery1.RecordCount = 0 then
      MessageDlg('The same information! Try again.', mtError, [mbOK], 0)
    else
      MyQuery1.Close;

    MyQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO uyeler (nick, mail, site, sifre) VALUES '+
                                            '(:nick, :mail, :site, :sifre)';

    MyQuery1.ParamByName('nick').AsString := Edit1.text;
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('mail').AsString := Edit2.text;
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('site').AsString := Edit3.text;
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('sifre').AsString := Edit4.text;
    MyQuery1.Execute;

    Button1.Enabled := False;
    MessageDlg('Mission complate!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);

    Edit1.Clear;
    Edit2.Clear;
    Edit3.clear;
    Edit4.Clear;

    PageControl2.Visible := False;
    PageControl1.Visible := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    MessageDlg('Information is missing! Try again.', mtWarning,[mbOK],0);    
  end;
end;
```

How can I prevent signing up with the same? What should I do in this case?

Comment: You are overwriting the value in `MyQuery1.Params[0]`

Comment: **MyQuery1.Params[0], [1], [2]** I did so, but did not

Comment: Then update your post with your real code. I can see you have 3 lines where you're assigning value to the `MyQuery1.Params[0]` in a sequence.

Comment: @jcho360: Read the question title. It's allowing multiple users to be created, and the poster doesn't want that to happen.

Comment: user id as unique key? or PK?

Comment: The title of this question is bad.

Comment: @jachguate, You are so intelligent. I little know English. This is not enough for you?

Comment: Ankara, don't take it personal.  I'm not English expert also, but the problem is not in the English language, but the over-localization of it.  For example, you mention _signup_ but it looks like you're trying just to avoid duplicates in a database, maybe you use it to _signup_ the users of your app, but it is unrelated to the question.  I understand you're newbie, but I insist that you have to think twice before writing a question title and try to put it in general terms, and your chances to get a good answer increases, because more people will be interested in read your question.

Comment: @Ankara, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) in the FAQ, and remember to **Make it relevant to others**, StackOverflow is more about community than just you.

Comment: @Ankara in addition to what others said I would: check if "trimmed" fields are empty, i.e. if (Trim(edit1.Text) <> '') and ..., otherwise people can type spaces, also, in your SELECT query, you might want to limit the result to 1, i.e. LIMIT 1, there's no point in going over the entire table once you've found one record that is the same as the new one would be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO the answer posted by [@Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765808/how-can-i-avoid-storing-duplicates-in-the-database-in-this-code/11765849#11765849) should work fine, but since you are finding troubles. I suggest you to try with this code. Its just the difference in the executing the queries.

*I am considering the field datatypes to be Char or VarChar, hence " " while entering the data values*

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled:=false;

  if (edit1.Text <> '') and (edit2.Text <> '') and 
     (edit3.Text <> '') and (edit4.Text <> '') then
  begin
    MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Add(' select* from uyeler where nick="'+edit1.text+'"' +
                      'and mail="'+edit2.text+'" and site="'+edit3.text+'"');
    MyQuery1.Execute;

    if not MyQuery1.IsEmpty then   //--- can also use MyQuery1.RecordCount >0 
      MessageDlg('The same information! Try again.', mtError,[mbOK],0)
    else
    begin            //--- no duplicates present 
      MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      MyQuery1.SQL.Add(' INSERT INTO uyeler (nick, mail, site, sifre) VALUES '+
                            '("'+edit1.text+'", "'+edit2.text+'","'+edit3.text+'", "'+edit4.text+'")');

     try
        MyQuery1.Execute;
      finally
        MyQuery1.SQL.Clear;
      end;

     MessageDlg('Mission complate!', mtInformation,[mbOK],0);

     Edit1.Clear;
     Edit2.Clear;
     Edit3.clear;
     Edit4.Clear;

     PageControl2.Visible:=false;
     PageControl1.Visible:=true;
    end;                        
  end;                 
  else
   MessageDlg('Information is missing! Try again.', mtWarning,[mbOK],0);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would typically use unique indexes on the underlying MySQL table to enforce this.

Comment: This isn't really an answer; it's probably a great comment, but it doesn't answer the question asked, which was "what's wrong with my code, because it allows duplicates". You can tell by the question itself, though, that this poster is fairly new to SQL and databases, and your one liner would really need to be made into a more complete answer, maybe as an alternate solution after answering the question itself.

Comment: It's a better answer imo because it places the validation where it needs to be.

Comment: @JohnEasley: So the question is "How do I make homemade bread?", and you think "I prefer bagels, because it's faster to open the package and toast them." is a better answer? Apples and oranges - the question was specifically "What's wrong with this code?" and this answer says "Don't use code.", and that doesn't answer the question asked. I've been polite and given the poster a chance to edit it without downvoting it, but I really should, because it's not a correct answer *to the question asked*.

Comment: Sticking to your bread analogy - he made crappy bread and you added lemon flavoring. This answer explains concisely how to bake better bread.

Comment: @John, no. He made bread and this answer said "Don't bake.". Again, apples to oranges, but it's apparent you and I don't agree. :-) The general policy here is "Answer the question asked when possible, and then provide alternatives and explain why they're better". The second half of that is here; the first is missing. (And calling someone's code "crappy" isn't very polite.)

Answer (score 1):

You're checking  the wrong result. You need to change your test to

```
if MyQuery1.RecordCount > 0 then // At least one match found already
```

Better yet, if `MyDac` supports it, is to use

```
if not MyQuery1.IsEmpty then  // row already exists.
```

Actually, you have more issues than that, though. You have a mismatched `begin` and `end` block, because right now you're always running  the insert part of the method. As @TLama says, you're also using the same pameter multiple times, assigning `nick`, `mail`, and `site` the all the same value. Use named parameters instead (shown below in both the SQL and the parameter assignments).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  UserExists: Boolean;
begin
  Button1.Enabled:=false;

  if (edit1.Text <> '') and (edit2.Text <> '') and 
     (edit3.Text <> '') and (edit4.Text <> '') then
  begin
    MyQuery1.Close;
    MyQuery1.SQL.Text :=' select* from uyeler '+
                        'where nick=:nick and mail=:mail and site=:site';

    MyQuery1.ParamByName('nick').AsString:=edit1.text;
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('mail').AsString:=edit2.text;
    MyQuery1.ParamByName('site').AsString:=edit3.text;
    MyQuery1.open;
    try
      UserExists := not MyQuery1.IsEmpty;
    finally
      MyQuery1.Close;
    end;

    if UserExists then
      MessageDlg('The same information! Try again.', mtError,[mbOK],0)
    else
    begin            // <<--- Added begin
      MyQuery1.SQL.Text :=' INSERT INTO uyeler (nick, mail, site, sifre) VALUES '+
                                              '(:nick, :mail, :site, :sifre)';

      MyQuery1.ParamByName('nick').AsString        := Edit1.text;
      MyQuery1.ParamByName('mail').AsString        := Edit2.text;
      MyQuery1.ParamByName('site').AsString        := Edit3.text;
      MyQuery1.ParamByName('sifre').AsString        := Edit4.text;
      try
        MyQuery1.Execute;
      finally
        MyQuery1.Close;
      end;
    end;                      // <------------ Moved end from below where marked

    MessageDlg('Mission complate!', mtInformation,[mbOK],0);

    Edit1.Clear;
    Edit2.Clear;
    Edit3.clear;
    Edit4.Clear;

    PageControl2.Visible:=false;
    PageControl1.Visible:=true;
  end            // <------------- removed extra end caused by addition above
  else
   MessageDlg('Information is missing! Try again.', mtWarning,[mbOK],0);
end;
```

Comment: Also the OP is only filling the first parameter `MyQuery1.Params[0]`

Comment: Warning appears but registeration process continues.

Comment: Rodrigo and TLama, yeah. Caught that after I'd posted the intial edit. Fixed (with help, it looks like). :-)

Comment: @Ankara, you need to be more specific. What "warning appears"?

Comment: @Ken White, `MessageDlg('The same information! Try again.', mtError,[mbOK],0)` but registeration process continues.

Comment: @Ankara, see my edit on the line `if MyQuery1.RecordCount` - it somehow got lost in my large edit, even though I mentioned it in the opening text.

Comment: I guess the problem but I dont know how to solve it. The problem can be about "**if ,then, else, end**"

Comment: It's not possible for the code I posted to add the same user twice. If you're still getting that, you're not using the code I posted. Check the parameters in both SQL statements, the setting of the parameters (the change from `Params[0]` to ParamByName` in **both** places they're used), and the exact placement of the `begin` and `end` statements. (There was one more fix I needed to make - the query could be left open when the method ended.) Otherwise, it should work just as it's written.

Comment: @Ken White, This codes provided does not work properly. There is no difference. Registration process are still... Also: Value assigned to 'UserExists' never used.

Comment: @Ankara. The code provided works **fine**. If it's not working for you, you're not using it. (As for the hint about the unused value, I'll remove the single line (that you didn't identify) that's causing it.) I give up - if I post the **exact** code for you to use, and you can't manage to copy and paste it properly, I can't do any more to help. :-(